# Handling an 'else' type situation within a loop

Tags: c++

I have a homework problem for my C++ class and the problem wants us to have the user input a wavelength and then output the correct type of radiation. **The point to notice is that there are more Wave Name values than there are Wave Lengths.**

My solution is listed below:

```
const double WAVE_LENGTH[] = { 1e-11, 1e-8, 4e-7, 7e-7, 1e-3, 1e-2 };
const char* WAVE_NAME[] = { "Gamma Rays", "X Rays", "Ultraviolet", "Visible Light", "Infrared", "Microwaves", "Radio Waves" };

double waveLength;

std::cout << "Enter a wavelength in decimal or scientific notation\nWavelength: ";
std::cin >> waveLength;

for (unsigned short i = 0U; i < 6U; ++i)
{
    if (waveLength < WAVE_LENGTH[i])
    {
        std::cout << "The type of radiation is " << WAVE_NAME[i] << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    if (i == 5U) // Last iteration
        std::cout << "The type of radiation is " << WAVE_NAME[i + 1] << std::endl;
}
```

My question is regarding my approach at solving the problem, specifically within the loop. I can't seem to find a way to handle all the situations without creating two conditions inside the loop which seems like it is a poor design. I realize I could use a series of if/else if statements, but I figured a loop is cleaner. Is my approach the best way or is there a cleaner way of coding this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you have five bounded intervals and two unbounded ones. This will have to show in your loop one way or another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can simplify your loop to this:

```
unsigned short i;

for (i = 0U; i < 6U; ++i)
{
    if (waveLength < WAVE_LENGTH[i])
    {
        break;
    }
}
std::cout << "The type of radiation is " << WAVE_NAME[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: This will always execute the outside `std::cout`. But his original code, might not.

Comment: Indeed - look at the original loop again - I think you'll find that my version gives identical behaviour.

Comment: You're using i outside of the loop it's declared in. Did you intend to move it out of the loop? For the record, there's a couple decent solutions, but I like this one the best. It also means you have one less line to change when the output changes on you...

Comment: `unsigned short i` goes out of scope at the end of the loop, it needs to be declared _before_ the loop.  (@Nawaz: under what condition does it not display?)

Comment: @Mooing Duck/glowcoder: thanks - missed the scope problem - now fixed.

Comment: I like this.. I knew there was a cleaner way to do this. Thanks! (=

Answer (score 1):

In my view a somewhat cleaner design is to add positive infinity as the last element of `WAVE_LENGTH`. This way your corner case will  require no special handling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

...

const double WAVE_LENGTH[] = { 1e-11, 1e-8, 4e-7, 7e-7, 1e-3, 1e-2,
                               std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() };
const char* WAVE_NAME[] = { "Gamma Rays", "X Rays", "Ultraviolet", "Visible Light",
                            "Infrared", "Microwaves", "Radio Waves" };

double waveLength;

std::cout << "Enter a wavelength in decimal or scientific notation\nWavelength: ";
std::cin >> waveLength;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(WAVE_LENGTH) / sizeof(WAVE_LENGTH[0]); ++i)
{
    if (waveLength < WAVE_LENGTH[i])
    {
        std::cout << "The type of radiation is " << WAVE_NAME[i] << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also note how I've avoided having to hard-code the length of the array (`6U` in your code) in the loop's terminal condition.

Comment: The infinity idea is interesting.. Kind of makes sense since we are dealing with infinity in this situation as well.

Comment: you even don't any condition as the loop always breaks on infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the last iteration in the same if. Notice there is no test anymore itn for.

```
for (unsigned short i = 0U; ; ++i)
{
    if (i == 6 || waveLength < WAVE_LENGTH[i])
    {
        std::cout << "The type of radiation is " << WAVE_NAME[i] << std::endl;
        break;
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can add a extra wavelength set to MAX_FLOAT (or whatever is called in C++) or set the last one to zero and exit if wave_length[i] == 0.0. That way you don't need to "know" the number of wave lengths.